# miniltx color conflict

Tags: color, plain-tex

I am using Plain TeX for a document that has illustrations and uses colored type.  I find that when I load both `miniltx` and `color` I get an error message on the console.  Looking at the files where the error occurs I see that I am way out of my depth.  Can someone suggest how to overcome this problem?  Here is my source code and the console message

Source Code

```
\input color


\hrule


\input miniltx

\def\Gin@driver{dvips.def}
\input graphicx.sty

\resetatcatcode


\centerline{ \includegraphics[width=2.5in]{Klein125}}
\kern -20pt
\centerline{Figure 125}
\hrule

\bye
```

Console message

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Klein in TeX copy.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/plain/graphics-pln/color.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/plain/graphics-pln/miniltx.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/plain/graphics-pln/miniltx.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty:34: Use of \
@ doesn't match its definition.
l.34 \@m
        akeother\"%
? 
Process aborted
```

Comment: If I replace `Klein125` with a file present on my machine (`example-image-duck` from `duckuments` or `example-image` from `mwe`) the file compiles fine for me (up-to-date MikTeX 2.9).

Comment: I can reproduce the issue if I move the `\resetatcatcode` to before `\input graphicx.sty` in the MWE. Can you double-check its position?

Comment: in any case `color.tex` and `graphics.tex` both input `miniltx` so there is no need to input `miniltx` explicitly. Also of course just using latex is simpler and more robust than  using plain but inputting half the latex format  at run time.

Comment: This clarifies what is going on.  I have been loading miniltx twice and that is probably what is screwing things up.  I will experiment and see what happens.  Thank you.

Comment: \input color  \input graphics.sty  \resetcatcode  figure 125  \bye  Gives the same problem.  Switching to LaTeX would require my tossing out my macros and choices of fonts.  Switching to MikTeX would require my learning a new environment, even more disruptive.  The odd thing is that I am using color and graphics in a similar document on my system with no problems.

Comment: Please check that the example *as posted* really reproduces the *exact* error  in the `.log` file. Please also update your post with your new findings and your new tries and also upload the `.log` file for those tests. It becomes a bit tricky to keep track of experiments if they are only mentioned incompletely in the comments.

Comment: SOURCE CODE \input color \input graphicx.sty  \resetcatcode Figure 125  \bye
ERROR MESSAGE
dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty:34: Use of \
@ doesn't match its definition.
l.34 \@m
        akeother\"%

Comment: What about `\input color \input graphicx Figure 125 \bye`? (no `.sty` extension for `graphicx` to catch the `.tex` and no `\resetcatcode` because it is implicit in both `color.tex` and `graphicx.tex`)

Comment: Still the same error message.  Perhaps my package is corrupted, but color and graphics work together in another file O.K.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code works without error in texlive 2020

[image]

```
\input color


\hrule


\input miniltx

\def\Gin@driver{dvips.def}
\input graphicx.sty

\resetatcatcode


\centerline{ \includegraphics[width=2.5in]{example-image}}
\kern -20pt
\centerline{Figure 125}
\hrule

\bye
```